# Elasticsearch keys with names that are substrings of one another

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been playing with Elasticsearch for about a day now, so I'm extremely new. I am trying to `POST`/import a simple document:

```
{
    "compression" : "none",
    "compression.level" : "0"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
  {
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "object mapping for [compression] tried to parse field [compression] as object, but found a concrete value"
}
],
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "object mapping for [compression] tried to parse field [compression] as object, but found a concrete value"
},
"status": 400
}
```

From what I understand, Elasticsearch will first see `"compression" : "none"` and create a key named `compression` of type string? Then when it sees `"compression.level" : "0"`, it sees that as key "compression" with.. an object value of `.level" : "0"`? Or...I don't really know.

How could I get this to work as expected? Or why doesn't it work as I'm expecting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compression` is of type `object` and you are trying to pass a `string` value, which you can't directly pass. And below error message explains it properly.

> object mapping for [compression] tried to parse field [compression] as
>   object, but found a concrete value

An object type can have multiple `sub-fields`, which are denoted by `.` and you can pass the individual value to those subfields. So in your case, you can pass the value of `compression.level`.

Please refer official ES doc for more explanation and examples. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html

Looks like you are using the dynamic mapping, in this case when elasticsearch sees the field name with `.`, then if there is a corresponding field with the same name but without `.`, then it automatically converts it to `object` type, which is happening in your case.

Let me know what is your requirement if you want a key for your value `none`, then you should create a document like :

```
{
    "compression.stategy" : "none", // notice its a another sub-field. 
    "compression.level" : "0"
}
```

And you can check all the sub-fields by hitting the `_mapping` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

**Coming to your understanding(if you are using dynamic mapping), it's bit different, ES will first see `"compression" : "none"` then try to map it to text field, but then it sees another field `compression.level` and as it uses `.` in field name, and `compression` is already present, hence start treating `compression` as an object type.**